# Order of destruction in the case of multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance

Is the order of destruction well defined in the case of multiple inheritance?

```
struct A
{
   ~A(){std::cout << "A\n";}   
};

struct B
{
   ~B(){std::cout << "B\n";}   
};

struct AB : public B, public A
{
    ~AB(){std::cout<<"AB\n";}   
};

int main()
{
    AB ab;
}
```

For the given code my compiler prints:

```
AB
B
A
```

But I use more complex constructs (including `CWinApp`), I get different results. So is the order well-defined? And if so, what is the ordering rule?

Comment: Yes, destruction is in reverse order of declaration.

Comment: What compiler are you running that that's what gets printed? Should AB, A, B.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [class.dtor]:

> Bases and
>   members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion of their constructor (see 12.6.2).

The constructor ordering, from [class.base.init]:

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the following order:
>   — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized [ ... ]
>   — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration order as they appear in the *base-specifier-list*
>   (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).

For your example:

```
struct AB : public B, public A
```

The construction order is `B` then `A` then `AB`. So the destruction order is `AB` then `A` then`B`.

Answer (score 6):

The C++11 Standard makes this clear (S10.1), for multiple inheritance

> The order of derivation is not significant except as specified by the
>   semantics of initialization by constructor (12.6.2), cleanup (12.4),
>   and storage layout (9.2, 11.1).

But you can guarantee that the destruction order is the reverse of the construction.

Comment: This means every order of destruction is possible?

Comment: So the order isn't significant except for cleanup. What's the order for cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

From the [friendly manual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8183zf3x%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) (abbreviating #2 a bit):

> 1. The class's destructor is called.
> 2. Destructors for nonstatic members in reverse order of declaration.
> 3. Destructors for nonvirtual base classes are called in the reverse order of declaration.
> 4. Destructors for virtual base classes are called in the reverse order of declaration.

So your compiler emits code that destructs in the order AB, B, A.

[Edit 20150725: Barry's repeated comments eventually led me to notice that I had typoed "This is not" as "This is also".  Of course, having typed it, I couldn't see it until I *did*.  Meh.  Thus, the one changed word in the following.]

This is ***not*** the order from isocpp.org's [FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-vi-dtor-order).  That entry refers to the same question about constructor ordering, where the text "Note that the order B1 and then B2 (or B1a then B1b) is determined by the order that the base classes appear in the declaration of the class, not in the order that the initializer appears in the derived class’s initialization list." appears, highlighting that declaration order is the relevant order.

Comment: You say "reverse order of declaration", but then you say "AB, B, A". Which is it? B was declared before A.

Comment: @Barry : From the source: struct A is declared on line 1 (and immediately defined), then struct B is declared on line 6, then struct AB is declared on line 11.  So, clearly, A is declared before B.  Additionally, this order actually matches the output of his code sample.

Comment: It's the order that they are declared as bases that matters, not the order the classes themselves are declared. In the base specifier list, B is first.

Comment: Because the compiler is wrong. The standard is pretty clear on this.